# Sorting related pictures to artists - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need anyones help, i'll really appriciate that.

I have made 2 JOiN-s. As a fact I have 3 Tables

1. Table with names of Artists (m)
2. Table with Product iformations, in this case Picture addresses (p)
3. Table that has id of Artists and id of Products. (pmx)

here's the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
    m.manufacturer_id ,
    m.mf_name ,
    p.product_id ,
    p.product_full_image
FROM
    jos_vm_product_mf_xref AS pmx 
JOIN
    jos_vm_manufacturer AS m ON m.manufacturer_id = pmx.manufacturer_id 
JOIN
    jos_vm_product AS p ON p.product_id = pmx.product_id 
WHERE
    m.mf_chars = 'm'
```

the effect that I'm trying to achieve is like on [http://www.ugallery.com/ArtistList.aspx?RC=1][1]

and in fact I'm getting just:

1. Name1 - prod1
2. Name1 - prod2
3. Name2 - prod1
4. Name1 - prod3

I want it, after foreach (smth) { smth } to get:

1. Name1 - prod1 prod2, prod3
2. Name2 - prod1 prod2
3. Name3....etc

   ```
   <ul>
   <?php foreach ($this->artistlist as $item) 
               {   ?>
       <li><a href="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=<?php echo $item->manufacturer_id; ?>"><?php echo $item->mf_name; ?></a>

       <a href="index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=<?php echo $item->product_id; ?>&option=com_virtuemart">
           <img src="components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/<?php echo $item->product_full_image; ?>" height="75px">
       </a>

       </li>
   <?php   } ?>
   </ul>
   ```

this is PHP code that I'm using for now...

So plz, plz, plz.... Can anyone help me?

Here's the piece of the code

```
foreach ($this->artistlist as $picture) {
   if(!isset($artists[$picture['manufacturer_id']])) {   <---this is line 22
      $artists[$picture['manufacturer_id']] = array(
         'name'=>$picture['mf_name']
      );
   }
```

So... the error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\ta\components\com_artists\views\artists\tmpl\default.php on **line 35**

foreach($artist['pictures'] as $pictureId=>$pictureFullImage) {  <--- line 35

And another additional question: 
  the outputed HTML is like this:

```
       <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/ta/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;page=shop.browse&amp;manufacturer_id=3">Giorgi Mihkeil</a>

**</li><li>** <--- and, can we get rid of this pieces? *<a href="/ta/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&amp;page=shop.browse&amp;manufacturer_id=$picture->artist_id"></a>* <-- what is this link? where does it come from?    
    <a href="/ta/index.php?page=shop.product_details&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=1&amp;option=com_virtuemart">
       <img src="/ta/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/Lonely_Boat_4cfa773e83874.jpg" height="75px">
    </a>    <a href="/ta/index.php?page=shop.product_details&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=2&amp;option=com_virtuemart">
       <img src="/ta/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/Naked_Couple_4cfbd12805f5b.jpg" height="75px">
    </a>    <a href="/ta/index.php?page=shop.product_details&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=4&amp;option=com_virtuemart">
       <img src="/ta/components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/Lonely_Boat_4d246dbef30e1.jpg" height="75px">
    </a></li></ul>
```

now this html give's smth like:  `<ul><li>NAME </li><li> <img1><img2><img3> </li></ul>`
can we get smth like:  `<ul><li>NAME <img1><img2><img3> </li></ul>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got your pictures in an array already:

```
$artists = array();

foreach($pictures as $picture) {
   if(!isset($artists[$picture['manufacturer_id']])) {
      $artists[$picture['manufacturer_id']] = array(
         'name'=>$picture['mf_name']
      );
   }

   $artists[$picture['artist_id']]['pictures'][$picture['product_id']] = $picture['product_full_image'];
}

foreach($artists as $artistId=>$artist) {
   echo $artist['name'].': ';
   foreach($artist['pictures'] as $pictureId=>$pictureFullImage) {
      echo "<img src='{$pictureFullImage}' />";
   }
}
```

This is a bit more complex than the solution presented by dqhendricks because it doesn't just store the ID of the artist, but also his/her name. That means there's an additional layer of arrays involved.

Based on your comment below: http://pastebin.com/2Cuyvp3U - I think this should do it? Don't know what the mf_prior field is you suddenly introduced though...

Comment: wow... thanks for such a fast replys!!!
I used this code... and it gives me an error of the frist line - foreach - says Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

So.. I might play little dumm right now... but there are some things I can't make clear through this code... 

I have this array in foreach - foreach ($this->artistlist as $item) ....

Comment: <?php  foreach ($this->artistlist as $item) 
     {   ?>
   <li><a href="index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=<?php echo $item->manufacturer_id; ?>"><?php echo $item->mf_name; ?></a>
   
   <a href="index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=<?php echo $item->product_id; ?>&option=com_virtuemart">
    <img src="components/com_virtuemart/shop_image/product/<?php echo $item->product_full_image; ?>" height="75px"><?php echo $item->mf_prior; ?>
   </a>
   
   </li>
  <?php }  ?>

this is my code....

Comment: Might want to add that to your question - code in comments tends to format quote horribly ;)

Comment: Any ideas how to make my site work according to you code? It is killing me really... i've been thinking of it two days already, I found on this site code like yours but couldn't adjust it to my case...

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to a pastebin, based on what you've just added to the question :)

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\ta\components\com_artists\views\artists\tmpl\default.php on line 22  --- this is what i get... i checked google for some answer, some say it's because of PHP version... maybe you know :)

Comment: just make sure you are not using echo to display the value of the string. remember, this is a class array not a string so echo will not work --- this is what someone wrote for someones question from here http://www.webune.com/forums/cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array-php.html

Comment: I pasted the 22nd line  in my question, so that you can see which part is giving "error"

Comment: Hi Mikey - yeah, my bad. Where the data from the original is accessed using []'s, it should be ->'s. I had the data in an array for easier testing, forgot to convert them back to -> when posting the answer.

Comment: Hello Kander!! Thanks for you help. Could you update the code on http://pastebin.com/2Cuyvp3U  with ->, because I'm not familiar with the syntax for arrays you used. I maganed to change first 2 lines, but then I got into a dead end.

Comment: wow, thanks, it really is looking how I wanted but there's one more thing, an error... Warning: Attempt to modify property of non-object in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\ta\components\com_artists\views\artists\tmpl\default.php on line 23    ---- 23rd line is 

      $artists->$picture->manufacturer_id = array(
        'name'=>$picture->mf_name

and i don't see the artist's name (mf_name) i guess that's because of this error

Comment: Kander, thank you very much for your effort, I mean, really thank you... Then the technical idea changed and I did it other way.. But anyway, you saved my day when I needed help. :)

Comment: Hi Mikey - you're welcome. I know how daunting working on PHP code that's a bit beyond what you're familiar with can be - especially implementing something like Joomla/Virtuemart can be a real pain. Best of luck with the new idea!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you'd use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for that.

```
SELECT
    m.mf_name ,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.product_id),
    p.product_full_image
FROM
    jos_vm_product_mf_xref AS pmx 
JOIN
    jos_vm_manufacturer AS m ON m.manufacturer_id = pmx.manufacturer_id 
JOIN
    jos_vm_product AS p ON p.product_id = pmx.product_id 
WHERE
    m.mf_chars = 'm'
GROUP BY m.mf_name
```

But if you're selecting pictures, you can't use that, you'll have to do it in your application language, using a Hash.

Comment: My first reaction was GROUP_CONCAT as well... might still work, if you can work parse the GROUP_CONCAT result in the PHP processing it so that it fills the IMG tags.

Comment: Yeah i already tried that but actually when making this query into MySQL's Query tab, I get only 1 image of that artist

Answer (score 0):

add an order by to your query

```
 ORDER BY  m.manufacturer_id ,p.product_id
```

An ordered query will be far easier to parse on your foreach loops.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to process this PHP side. In seudo code.

```
$record_list = array();
while ($row_result) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row_result['name'], $record_list)) {
        $record_list[$row_result['name']] = array();
    }
    $record_list[$row_result['name']][] = $row_result['value'];
}
var_dump($record_list);
```

This will make a multi dimensional array in the format that you are looking for.